# standard wpGallery for post won't work

Tags: posts, gallery

I'm trying to get the standard wpGallery running in my post.
[I followed this tutorial.](http://en.support.wordpress.com/images/gallery/)

But I can't get it working.
This is what my editor shows while editing a page:

[image]

But at the front-end nothing displays..
I've edited the TwentyTwelve theme to get a custom layout so I delete some things in the page.php, content.php and several files.

Someone familiair with this problem or knows what I can do to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work with original, unmodified TwentyTwelve (or other native theme)?

Comment: @Rarst No it doens't. Someone who can help me with this?